# Better ways of getting data from a backend to the frontend using ExpressJS and EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I want to get some data from the backend after the page has been rendered when a given event takes place. I'm using express for the backend and EJS as my templating language. Here's my solution:

The Express Backend

```
app.get('/getprice', (req, res) => {

// Parse the query string and retrieve params for the API.
const queryString = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
const exchange = queryString.exch.trim();
const ticker = queryString.ticker.trim();

// Use the 'KiteConnect' API to get some data.
// Simply put, I expect a JSON object as the response from which I'll extract an integer.

kc.getOHLC([`${exch}:${ticker}`])
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
// Send the response as a JSON on /getprice.
    res.json(response);
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    res.json("Failed to get last price of the requested trading symbol.");
    });
});
```

The JS Frontend

```
async function getPrice(ticker) {
        
        // GET request to my Express Backend for some data.

        const OHLC = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/getprice?ticker=${ticker}`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(res => res)
        .catch(e => e);

        // Extracting useful data from the parsed JSON.
        const currentPrice = OHLC[`BSE:${ticker.trim()}`].last_price;

        // Displaying the data inside an HTML element.
        document.querySelector('#price').textContent = currentPrice;
    }

    // Executing the above function with a param.
    getPrice(clickedCompany.firstChild.textContent);

}
```

This is the first serious nodeJS app I'm developing. I know the error handling is terrible. It's here to explain my problem. My question is, can I somehow get this data without making a fetch request? Essentially, I'm making two requests here; one goes from the front end to the backend from where the next one goes to another API's backend. Isn't this inefficient? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By a quick look at the Kite docs it seems the `KiteConnect` is only server-side client and they do not have a browser-side client. Probably to make it more secure. So what you're doing is correct.

Comment: @molda Thank you very much. Yes, I'm using their docs as a reference.